# "Not only ... but also" —parallelism in a particular case

Tags: word-order, subject-verb-inversion, parallelism

I have been looking around to find an answer to my question, but I was unable to find one that addressed my specific problem.

I want to create the following sentence, but I'm not sure whether it's correct.

> "Not only the world has changed during this time but also we have in particular."

I apologize in advance if I have overlooked an easy solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the word order:

**Not only has the world changed, but, in particular, also have we**

> To add emphasis, we can use *not only* at the beginning of a clause.
>   When we do this, we invert the subject and the verb:
>
> Not only was it raining all day at the wedding but also the band was late.
>
> Not only will they paint the outside of the house but also the inside.
>
> When there is no auxiliary verb or main verb be, we use do, does, did:
>
> Not only did she forget my birthday, but she also didn’t even apologise for forgetting it.
>   - *[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also)*

I have a slight problem with the "in particular" bit, though. It's rather clunky and really needs the other inversion "also *have we*" ("we have also" might work, but it's tempting to expect the sentence to continue "we  have also done...)

If I was writing it I think I'd put

> Not only has the world changed but, in particular, so have we.

Using *so* instead of *also*. It's shorter and directs the emphasis to the end. (Though you still need the second inversion.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer and including the link from Cambridge!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are very close, I reworded it slightly.

*Not only has the world has changed during this time, but also we have in particular.*

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast! That was actually the other way I thought of but I wasn't sure. I will go with the answer of Margana though.

Comment: Ok then, also this shorter version may have more impact. _Not only has the world changed during this time, but so have we._